# Inserting records at a time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, insert-update

I have 2 table TableA and TableB I want to insert all records at a time from TableA to TableB if the records are not in TableB

Please help  thank you

Answer (score 2):

Assuming they are sharing the same primary key.

```
insert TableB
select A.* 
from TableA A 
left join TableB B ON A.pk = B.pk 
where B.pk is null
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
INSERT INTO TableB
SELECT * FROM TableA
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM TableB
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate form of sambo's answer.

```
INSERT TableB
SELECT *
FROM TableA A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM TableB B
    WHERE A.pk = B.pk )
```

Comment: Whoever down marked this is not acting with reason.  This works perfectly fine...  I do prefer the LEFT JOIN approach when comparing tables, but this is NOT wrong...

Comment: Why thank you Dems.  In fact it might perform significantly different (better or worse) but it's a very common pattern.